# Popup window unload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one popup window, when user opens and closes popup window simultaneously, it is giving script error. Below code is used in popup window.

```
         <html>
    <head>
   <script src="../../StaticContent/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../../StaticContent/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
             function CloseWarning() {
                        return "Do you want to close the window";
                    }
function onload()
{
}
        </script></head>
            <body onbeforeunload="return CloseWarning();" onload="onload();">


              //Some html



            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(
                    function() {
            //Some code
            });
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I have tried degubbing, it is giving error at $(document).ready() line. I think because of closing the popup window before fully loading HTML is causing this problem.

Any clues???

Comment: Post the CloseWarning function

Comment: Have you included `jquery.js`?

Comment: In the HTML page of the popup?

Comment: What error you are getting tell us..

Comment: @Learner  "Object required." Line number is of $(document).ready(

Comment: @AshokD show your full mark up. including the Jquery scripts

Comment: You did not post relevant code. Where and how jQuery is included? What is the code in `//Some code`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Some code is just hiding and display the Div's.

Comment: Well, it's not good idea to mix the native `onload` and jQuery `ready` methods - remove your `onload="onload();` from the body tag and instead add the `onload()` call into `$(document).ready()` you already have..

Comment: @ShadowWizard tried doing that.. still no luck.. The problem is while closing the popup 2 out of 50 time (approx) this issue occurs.

Answer (score 2):

you have `()()` as double in the function declaration.  change like below.

```
 function CloseWarning(){
                    return "Do you want to close the window";
                }
```